# Unable to update a configuration file with the util:XmlFile task

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

My configuration file I try to update looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

...

    <jmsConfigurationSection>
        <jmsConfigurations>

            <jmsServer address="t3://localhost:7001" login="weblogic" password="weblogic1">
                <jmsConnectionFactories>
                    <jmsConnectionFactory name="jms/ConnectionFactory-0">
                        <jmsQueues>
                            <jmsQueue key="MeterMeasure" queueName="jms/Queue-0" />
                            <jmsQueue key="MeterEvent" queueName="jms/Queue-0" />
                        </jmsQueues>
                    </jmsConnectionFactory>
                </jmsConnectionFactories>
            </jmsServer>

            <jmsServer address="t3://localhost:7002" login="weblogic" password="weblogic1">
                <jmsConnectionFactories>
                    <jmsConnectionFactory name="jms/ConnectionFactory-0">
                        <jmsQueues>
                            <jmsQueue key="GatewayConfiguration" queueName="jms/Queue-0" />
                            <jmsQueue key="GatewayEvent" queueName="jms/Queue-0" />
                        </jmsQueues>
                    </jmsConnectionFactory>
                </jmsConnectionFactories>
            </jmsServer>

        </jmsConfigurations>
    </jmsConfigurationSection>

</configuration>
```

I must update this file in the context of a MSI. I use the util:XmlFile task like this :

```
<xsl:element name="util:XmlFile">
  <xsl:attribute name="Id">SetMeterServerAddress</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="Action">setValue</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="ElementPath">/configuration/jmsConfigurationSection/jmsConfigurations/jmsServer/jmsConnectionFactories/jmsConnectionFactory/jmsQueues/jmsQueue/[\[]@key='MeterMeasure'[\]]/../../../../@address</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="Value">[ORACLEMDM_METER_SERVER_ADDRESS]</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="File">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('[#', ../wix:File/@Id, ']')"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="SelectionLanguage">XPath</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="Sequence">1</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

But the task fails at runtime with the following error :

[image]

The XPath expression used in the util:XmlFile task works perfectly inside a PowerShell script or a console application.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an XPath-expert, but using [XMLQuire](http://qutoric.com/xmlquire/) to check the XPath didn't work either with the path you provided. IMHO two things are broken with the XPath-expression:

- The slash after jmsQueue has to be removed, as you are searching for the element `jmsQueue` with the conditional attribute value in the `key`-attribute and
- after you step back up in the tree you have to first select an element to be able to choose the related attribute, so just insert an additional `./` before the `@address` attribute at the end (i.e. you select the current node and then the `@address`-attribute in this node).

What worked for me (again: in XMLQuire) was the following XPath-expression:

```
/configuration/jmsConfigurationSection/jmsConfigurations/jmsServer/jmsConnectionFactories/jmsConnectionFactory/jmsQueues/jmsQueue[@key="MeterMeasure"]/../../../.././@address
```

or, as alternative (so you don't have to deal with the relative path):

```
/configuration/jmsConfigurationSection/jmsConfigurations/jmsServer[./jmsConnectionFactories/jmsConnectionFactory/jmsQueues/jmsQueue/@key = 'MeterMeasure']/@address
```

Can't tell you however why it did work in Powershell. Maybe it has some shortcuts or uses another version of XPath or whatever ;-) ...